# Making tracebacks clickable when running Python unit tests inside Sublime Text

Tags: python, sublimetext2, traceback

Is it possible to make output clickable: clicking the traceback line takes you to the corresponding Python file in Sublime Text edit tab?

[image]

Comment: You can patch the `traceback.print_exception` method but I do not know about sublime. You ask two questions.

Comment: Actually it is more like one question along the lines "What Sublime Text 2 features I need to use to make parts of command-line output clickable, so that ST2 maps them to open file on a line command". Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

[PythonTraceback](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/PythonTraceback) plugin makes it easier to navigate in python exceptions.
It will not make output clickable, but will allow to jump to a file in the traceback with couple of extra keystrokes. Check out [plugin description](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/PythonTraceback) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Accidental discovery: you actually *can* double-click on python tracebacks in Sublime Text output window to open corresponding file on corresponding line in edit tab.

Comment: I couldn't get this working. Have you anything special set up?